# Iraq, Syria and Egypt bloodshed

Tags: hadith, source-identification

Is there any reference in the Hadith that prophet Muhammad (PHUB) said that Iraq, Syria and Egypt fall apart and bloodshed? He said something like that in this line as part of sign that Dajjal is coming.

Answer (score 2):

> Abu Huraira reported Allah's Messenger (may peace be upon him) as saying: Iraq would withhold its dirhams and qafiz; Syria would withhold its mudd and dinar and Egypt would withhold its irdab and dinar and you would recoil to that position from where you started and you would recoil to that position from where you started and you would recoil to that position from where you started, the bones and the flesh of Abu Huraira would bear testimony to it.
>   <sup>—[Sahih Muslim, Book 55, Hadith 7459](http://sunnah.com/urn/269230)—</sup>

Comment: what does this mean? I guess a  lot of arab idioms are used which would have specific meanings, can you elaborate

Comment: Can you please explain what does this mean in simple English.